# An algebraic equation, summing exponential and other terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I am looking for a solution of an algebraic equation which seems simple...
Here it is, for a,b,c,d four constant real numbers, and x the unknown which is also real:
$$ x + e^{ax} + be^{cx} + d = 0 $$

I know that without the third term, the solution uses the W function of Lambert.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why would you expect it to have a solution in terms of well-known functions? A given case (with known values of a,b,c,d) would be easy to solve with standard approximation methods.

Comment: Your attempts would make viewers attracted, especially those who can solve such a thing.

Comment: And no, there is no way I know of that can solve this other than approximation methods as @almagest had suggested